# How to make a timer in python without freezing up the entire code

Tags: python, timer, pygame, sleep

I am coding Mario using Pygame and I'm coding the blocks right now. I want to make a timer so when I hit the block after a second the block goes back to its original position to make the hitting animation. The problem is when making the timer with sleep it freezer the entire game for the duration of the timer. I need the code to run and after a second that previous block of code to kick in.

I have tried using sleep to make the timer but it freezes the entire game. can anyone drop me some knowledge? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest you use the [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html) module and thread two functions.

At the end, you can format as such:

```
from threading import Thread
if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target = game()).start()
    Thread(target = timer()).start()
```

Another option is the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) module. You can set a timer and check when a certain time is hit with a if/while statement.

A third option is with the time module you used for sleep:

```
import time

max_time = #the time you want
start_time = time.time()
while (time.time() - start_time) < max_time:
    game()
```

Answer (score 9):

```
from threading import Timer

def timeout():
    # do your stuff here

t = Timer(number_of_seconds, timeout)
t.start()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
import sys
import time
import os

counter=0
s = 0
m = 0
n = int(input("Till How Many Seconds do you want the timer to be?: "))
print("")

while counter <= n:
    sys.stdout.write("\x1b[1A\x1b[2k")
    print(m, 'Minutes', s, 'Seconds')
    time.sleep(1)
    s += 1
    counter+=1
    if s == 60:
        m += 1
        s = 0

print("\nTime Is Over Sir! Timer Complete!\n")
beepPath = ("C:\\Users\\Farzeen Zargar\\Desktop\\Fizz Folder\\Videos\\Youtube Video Edits")
songs = os.listdir(beepPath)
os.startfile(os.path.join(beepPath, songs[13]))
```

Comment: Hi @LumberFizz, welcome to stackoverflow! You're answering a question which is over 1 year old. Please try to answer new questions, this is more helpful. And don't just add a code block. Explain your answer, so the creator is able to learn from you.