# Is there a Python function I can use for a condition like "If condition is still true after (3) seconds then dosomething"(

Tags: python, django

I am running a opencv through django and trying to save the data in sqlite.

I tried to use the sleep() in library time, but it only prevents my web app from running.

```
color = (0, 0, 255)


time.sleep(3)
if color == (0, 0, 255):
   save time
```

Comment: This looks like an X-Y problem. Please refer to this to rephrase your question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308444/ive-asked-an-xy-question-what-should-i-do-with-it

Answer (score 0):

You have more options to solve this, [here](https://blog.finxter.com/time-delay-in-python/) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55551007/how-to-make-a-timer-in-python-without-freezing-up-the-entire-code) are some examples.

Example with time and while loop:

```
import time

def your_func():
    #your code:
    #if color == (0, 0, 255):
    #save time

max_wait_time = 3.0 #the time you want in seconds
start_time = time.time()
while True:
    if (time.time() - start_time) >= max_wait_time:
        your_func()
        break
```

Example with Timer():

```
from threading import Timer

def your_func():
  #your code:
  #if color == (0, 0, 255):
  #save time

t = Timer(3.0, your_func)
t.start()
```